# Flickering laser scan data after static tf setup

Tags: gazebo, rviz, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My Gazebo model, written in Xacro, makes use of an Hokuyo laser scanner through the `libgazebo_ros_laser.so` plugin. Even though I specified a value for the `frameName` property, this plugin doesn't automatically publishes a transform from base_link to the frame I just specified. As the planar controller is automatically publishing the transformation of odom to base_link, I cannot understand **why the laser scanner controller is not doing so**.

I tried to manually specify a static transform publisher and everything seems to work, apart for the fact that **when I try to visualize the scanner data in rviz, it flickers** between the position it was in before I specified the transform and the one in which I *transported* it. They only differ a tiny little, but it is enough to notice, and I definitely don't think it is something healthy for my system.

I think it's **something related to the difference in frequency** between the transform publication and the laser data publication, but even setting both to 40ms nothing changes. I also cannot understand how rviz establishes how to display the laser data if I don't specify any transformation (because yes, it does).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/91606/flickering-laser-scan-data-after-static-tf-setup/) by [micpalmia](https://answers.ros.org/users/6343/micpalmia/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2013-10-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know this question is some month old, but I have a similar problem. I have also created an urdf model with a continuous joint and I want to rotate a link. Its working with an **tf::TransformBroadcaster** but like **micpalmia** said its ***flickering*** between its original pose and the pose set by the **tf::TransformBroadcaster**.

So has anybody any solution for this. It seems thats its just a little mistake we make, but I don't get it.

Best regards,
zumili

---

Originally posted by [zumili](https://answers.ros.org/users/3935/zumili/) with karma: 141 on 2014-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0